# How to test that the method doesn't throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, junit

This is how you write a test when you expect the targeted method to throw an exception.

```
@Test(expected = myExpectedException.class)
public void Test()
{

}
```

What if success is when the method doesn't throw an exception? Is there attribute for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an exception is thrown out of a test method, the test is considered to be in ERROR state, and is not counted as PASSED test.
In other words - you don't need any special treatment. Just call the method you want to test.

If you want to be really explicit about not allowing exceptions, you could add an [`ExpectedException`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) rule to your test:

```
public class MyClassTest {
    // The class under test
    // Initialized here instead of in a @Before method for brevity
    private MyClass underTest = new MyClass();

    // Not really needed, just makes things more explicit
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException noExceptionAllowed = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws SomeException {
        // If an exception is thrown, the test errors out, and doesn't pass
        myClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not throwing an exception and same time not anticipating it is always a SUCCESS
But if you explicitly want your test to tell the Spec that method may throw an exception but not this time you may use something like this

(*Found this code in my archives. I remember of referring it from internet*)

```
class MyAssertionRules {
    public static void assertDoesNotThrow(FailableAction action) {
        try {
            action.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Error("Unexpected Exception Thrown", ex);
        }
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface FailableAction {
    void run() throws Exception;
}
```

Then you can run your test like this

```
public void testMethodUnderTest() {
    MyAssertionRules.assertDoesNotThrow(serviceUnderTest::methodUnderTest);
}
```